# in jqgrid, how can i have the editform disappear after submit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

right now, when i click submit it sends a message to the server and updates the databased and refreshes the screen but it keeps the edit form popup on the screen.  Is there anyway to have it disappear once the submit is complete.   its kind of annoying because its a little unclear that you are done because the form just sits there (even through the grid has refreshed)

i have **closeAfterEdit** and **closeAfterAdd** set to **true** but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
 jQuery("#grid").navGrid("#pager",
        { },
        { height: 380, width: 500, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeAfterEdit: true, url: siteRoot + controller + "/Update" },
        { height: 380, width: 500, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeAfterAdd: true, url: siteRoot + controller + "/Add" },
        { reloadAfterSubmit: true, url: siteRoot + controller + "/Delete" },
        { multipleSearch: true }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can verify for example on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing.htm), that the `closeAfterEdit: true` and `closeAfterAdd: true` work in general.

You should try to start the code which not work in the debugger. If you post the URL where one could try the code you I could try to localize the problem. In the case you should use developer (uncompressed) version of jqGrid.

Comment: Turned out that I had another edidGridRow call that had closeAfterEdit not specified (which defaulted it to false)